# Django ALLOWED_HOSTS: OK to include 'localhost' on a deployed settings file?

Tags: django

I'm working in Django 1.8. I have set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` as follows, in both my local and deployed settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', 'my.deployed.url']
```

That way I don't need to change the settings in the deployed version. (Not that this is difficult to do, it's just convenient this way.)

Is there any security reason why I shouldn't have `localhost` there on the deployed settings on the remote server?

[From the docs I don't think there is](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts), but just wanted to check.

Comment: Interesting, but probably not very practical, you'd normally still want a separate settings file because of other settings.

Comment: With docker environments this becomes less and less the case as a lot of the config moves out of the containers and into the container integration layer.

Comment: Thanks, I just use environment variables for per-env settings, so no need for separate settings files (as per the Two Scoops of Django approach).

Comment: If I were you I'd look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/#run-manage-py-check-deploy

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As long as the app does not give superpowers to requests with 'localhost' in the Host http header it should be ok.

Comment: Any way to do a basic/general check if superpowers are given?  (If specifics are necessary: I'm deployed on AWS with Elasticbean, but I don't know enough of groups/users/unix to know if this is the case, let alone if there is a management setting in Django...)

Answer (score 6):

In Django 2.1.4, another solution is:
`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']`

Comment: When I tried the above `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']` , I got this error: `DisallowedHost at /

Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8000'. You may need to add '127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.`   But when I tried Gajmera's solution, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Peter Tillemans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30579484/943773), but if you wanted to be sure you could do something like...

### `settings.py`

```py
import sys

RUNNING_DEVSERVER = len(sys.argv) > 1 and (
    sys.argv[1] == "runserver" or sys.argv[1] == "runserver_plus"
)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".mydomain.com"]
if RUNNING_DEVSERVER:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS += ["localhost", "127.0.0.1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I have done. Like this I can change between localhost and production.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'your_deployed_host_url' ]

#and set your db to work on both db::

if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
    }
else:
    print("Postgres URL not found, using sqlite instead")
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1:

To quickly create a custom error page for the `404` error, place a file named `404.html` in your root template directory. For other errors like `400`, `500`, and `403`, follow the same pattern by creating `400.html`, `500.html`, and `403.html` respectively in the same root template directory.

Source: [Django documentation on serving static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve)

#### Method 2:

To customize error pages in Django, follow these steps:

1. Open your Django root `urls.py` file.
2. Add the following lines to associate specific views with different error codes:

   ```py
   from django.conf.urls import (handler400, handler403, handler404, handler500)

   handler400 = 'app.views.bad_request'
   handler403 = 'app.views.permission_denied'
   handler404 = 'app.views.page_not_found'
   handler500 = 'app.views.server_error'
   ```

   Replace `'app.views.bad_request'`, `'app.views.permission_denied'`, `'app.views.page_not_found'`, and `'app.views.server_error'` with the actual paths to your custom view functions for handling each error.

Source: [Django documentation on customizing error views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views)

> Keep in mind that if the `DEBUG` setting in your configuration is set to `True`, the custom `404` page you create might not be displayed. Instead, Django will show the URL configuration along with debugging information.